# How can I delete all expired rows older than one year?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// cookies
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
|   id    |         email           |     cookie       | date_time  |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
| int(11) |      varchar(50)        |   varchar(128)   |  int(11)   |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
| 1       | jack_2009@gmail.com     | ojer0f934mf2...  | 1467204523 |
| 2       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | ko4398f43043...  | 1467205521 |
| 3       | matrix_john23@gmail.com | 34fjkg3j438t...  | 1467205601 |
| 4       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | 0243hfd348i4...  | 1467206039 |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to delete all rows which are expired. expired means all old rows. old rows means every row which older than one year.

```
DELETE FROM cookies WHERE date_time < unix_timestamp() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
```

But my query seems not normal to me. Is there any better approach to do that?

Comment: `before last year` means `date_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: before last year means older than one year or created within last year

Comment: @Lashane You know, I don't know English very well, so maybe `before last year` isn't correct. A row is valid just for one year. So I want to remove all rows which have a less `date_time` than a year.

Comment: Your query is normal.

Comment: @juergend Look, my query has a calculation `(60 * 60 * 24 * 365)` for each row. Still are you believe it is normal?

Comment: maybe instead say last year, you could say  `delete if > 365 days old` to avoid confusion, if that is what you want.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Well this is what I want: `delete if < 365 days old`

Comment: @Stack please create index on date_time column (some extra information ) other than that you query is ok for me

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka Ah ok, thx

Comment: @Stack: No, the calculation is done one time. So nothing special about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use date_SUB interv 1 Year from now

```
 DELETE FROM cookies WHERE  date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 year))
```

Comment: I think no need to that `from_unixtime()`. Because the value of `date_time` column is as *unix time*

Comment: And I guess you have to add `from_unixtime()` for the other side: `from_unixtime(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 year))`

Comment: thanks  .. if from a side is unix time then the  other side  need too ..

Comment: Now seems correct ..! Or you can remove `from_unixtime()` function and use `unix_timestamp()` instead of `now()`.

Comment: It doesn't seem correct to me. I don't think you want the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function wrapped around an expression that returns a DATETIME. To return an integer number of seconds since 1/1/1970, use the **`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`** function.  e.g. **`intcol < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`**

Comment: The MySQL function is **`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`**.  (MySQL doesn't have a "unixtime" function.)

Comment: there is't `unixtime()` function in the MySQL, I think you're missing an under_line between `unix` and `timestamp`.